# Have I handled the errors correctly with this json_encode()?

Tags: php, jquery, json

How should I handle the two possible errors in this scenario? I'm not sure if this is the  recommended way, please can someone advise?

```
 if (isset($_GET['numberofwelds']) && isset($_GET['numberofconwelds']) 
            {
                // Now we know both values definitely exist, VALIDATE them
                $numwelds = $_GET['numberofwelds'];
                $numconwelds = $_GET['numberofconwelds'];

                if (is_int($numwelds) && is_int($numconwelds))
                {
                    // Calculate your total
                    $total = $numwelds + $numconwelds;
                    echo json_encode($total);
                }
                else
                {
                    $response = array("status" => "failure", "message" => "GET params were not numbers");
                    echo json_encode($response);
                    }

            else
            {
                 $response = array("status" => "failure", "message" => "GET params do not exist");
                 echo json_encode($response);
                 }
          }
```

Comment: you should encode to json error responses. Now you are obviously missing a bracket between first IF and last ELSE

Comment: Ok so you edited your code but which code are you using? Have you try it at least? What is your issue then?

Comment: What do you mean by handling two errors? Of course only one error will be reached at a time and like said, you should encode to JSON these $response

Comment: Couldn't you try on your side??? I'm not a debugging console you know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need to set the CONTENT-TYPE for the response in PHP.  This needs to be done before any output is set or you will need to use PHP's output buffer.

**First set the header with this:**

```
header("CONTENT-TYPE: application/json");
```

Otherwise you will need to parse the JSON in your JavaScript.

e.g.  $.parseJSON(jd);

**Secondly, if you want to return the JSON data for the response arrays, you can do the following:**

```
$response = array("status" => "failure", "message" => "GET params were not numbers");

echo json_encode($response);
```

With the response's CONTENT-TYPE set, you will now have a JSON Object in your JavaScript.

**E.g.**

**console.log(jd.status) will output: failure**

**console.log(jd.message) will ouput: GET params were not numbers**

*(Depending on the error that was generated.)*

*Just remember that these error does not replace jQuery's AJAX error.  These will be returned in the **success** method.  So you will handle them there.*

**E.g**

```
$.ajax({
  success:function(jd){
            console.log(jd.status);
          }
});
```

**Remember to set the "dataType" option for the ajax call to "json".**

**E.g**

```
$.ajax({
      dataType:"json"
    });
```